# how to create a subroutine that accepts all types of variable(scalar, hash, array or ref)

Tags: perl, perl-data-structures

How to create a subroutine that accepts all types of variable and determine if it's (scalar, hash, array or ref)

```
sub know_var {
    my $this_var = shift;

    if ($this_var eq "array"){
        print "This variable is an array!";
    } elsif ($this_var eq "hash") {
        print "This variable is a hash!";
    } elsif ($this_var eq "hash ref") {
        print "This variable is an hash reference!";
    } so on..

}

my @array = ('foor', 'bar');
my %hash  = (1 => "one", 2 => "two");
my $scalar = 1;
my $scalar_ref = \$scalar;
my $hash_ref = \%hash;
my $arr_ref = \@array;

know_var(@array);
know_var($scalar_ref);
and so on...
```

My goal for this is I want to create a subroutine that is similar to Data::Dumper,
and my first problem is to determine  what kind of variable am going to deal with.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [perlsub](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html#DESCRIPTION)

> The Perl model for function call and return values is simple: all functions are passed as parameters one single flat list of scalars, and all functions likewise return to their caller one single flat list of scalars. Any arrays or hashes in these call and return lists will collapse, losing their identities--but you may always use pass-by-reference instead to avoid this.

So, you can use references and [`ref()`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/ref.html) to check type of reference

```
sub know_var {
  my $this_var = shift;

  if (ref($this_var) eq "ARRAY") { 
    print "This variable is an array reference!";
  }
  elsif (ref($this_var) eq "HASH") { 
    print "This variable is an hash reference!";
  }
  elsif (ref($this_var) eq "SCALAR") { 
    print "This variable is an scalar reference!";
  }
  elsif (!ref($this_var)) { 
    print "This variable is plain scalar!";
  }

}

know_var(\@array);
know_var(\%hash);
know_var(\$scalar);
know_var($scalar);
```

Comment: Im still confused Mr. mpapec, so what do you mean all will be reference even if its just a scalar variable?

Comment: oh I see, How about for plain array and hash?

Comment: @Soncire you can't do the same for array and hash as these two are flattened into a single list when passed to subroutine, https://eval.in/101110

Comment: So the only way to pass an array or hash to subroutine is through by ref stored in a scalar variable? is that right SIr?

Comment: Thanks for enlightening me Cheers!!

Comment: hmmmm.... `$scalar = \@array; know_var($scalar);`. For your plan to work, you must always use `\ `.

Comment: @ikegami `$scalar` in case above should be plain, no a/href one.

Answer (score 1):

In the spirit of TIMTOWTDI, and in the interests of pimping my own wares, here's an alternative, using multisubs...

```
use v5.14;
use warnings;
use Kavorka qw( multi fun );

multi fun foobar (ArrayRef $x) {
   say "It's an array";
}

multi fun foobar (HashRef $x) {
   say "It's a hash";
}

multi fun foobar (Num $x) {
   say "It's a number: $x";
}

multi fun foobar (Str $x) {
   say "It's a string: $x";
}

foobar( [] );
foobar( {} );
foobar( 1.234 );
foobar( "Hello world" );
foobar( \*STDOUT );  # dies
```

Comment: Value-based polymorphism is awful. Often gives the wrong answer. e.g. `foobar("1.234")`. e.g. `foobar(!!0)` e.g. `use overload '0+' => sub { 123 }; foobar(bless({}))`

Comment: Same difference with `use overload '@{}' => sub {...}` and checking `ref($var)`. It's quite common in Perl to need to take a few extra precautions if you want to accept overloaded objects. The Types::TypeTiny type library provides `StringLike`, `ArrayLike`, `HashLike`, and `CodeLike` constraints. (It perhaps ought to also offer `ScalarRefLike`, `NumLike`, and `BoolLike` for completeness.)